# e.which is not working in IE 9

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to get the keycode value from the Javascript

```
   var whichCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
```

However, it is working fine except IE 9. It is returning undefined on the e.which.

Comment: Where is this code executed?
kindly add the complete code. you should use this within an event handler!

Comment: rather check for e.which: `var whichCode = e.which || e.keyCode;` assuming e is the event object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is this code executed? kindly add the complete code. you should use this within an event handler!
Assuming it is placed correctly try this

```
var keycodeValue = e.which || e.keyCode;
```

Where e is the event recieved

Answer (score 1):

`KeyboardEvent.which` has never been implemented in Internet Explorer and is considered as deprecated in other ones.

The MDN explains [how to most correctly handle keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) :

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) {
    return; // Should do nothing if the default action has been cancelled
  }

  var handled = false;
  if (event.key !== undefined) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.key and set handled true.
  } else if (event.keyIdentifier !== undefined) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.keyIdentifier and set handled true.
  } else if (event.keyCode !== undefined) {
    // Handle the event with KeyboardEvent.keyCode and set handled true.
  }

  if (handled) {
    // Suppress "double action" if event handled
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}, true);
```

Right now, assuming you're not handling the keyDown event, you could also use

```
var whichCode = e.charCode !== undefined ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
```

Note that this is [exactly how it is done in jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) for browser compatibility :

```
if ( event.which == null ) {
    event.which = original.charCode != null ? original.charCode : original.keyCode;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if it's mistake on my part; isn't strict comparison necessary here? I'm talking about `e.which != undefined`. `0 == undefined`, while `0 !== undefined`.

Comment: @bardzusny No, it isn't necessary : 0 isn't == to undefined. But it's cleaner, that's why I edited.

Comment: You're right, hard morning taking toll on me. I typed wrong code into node console.

Comment: Please, Wishy, don't edit my answer to change the essence of the code. Comment instead. `e.charCode || e.keyCode` would be a bug.